# Octave GUI not launching on MacOS 10.11

Tags: macos, homebrew, octave

I am currently using MacOS 10.11.6.

I installed the latest Octave as the [wiki](https://wiki.octave.org/Octave_for_macOS#Installing_a_Mac_OS_X_Bundle) explains using Homebrew, specifically the tap ***homebrew/core***.

When I launch it from the terminal, everything works fine, and no error is raised except for the fact that the GUI does not launch (even using the ***--force-gui*** flag). However when I try to plot something it works perfectly through ***XQuartz***.

Since I have no error/warning raised, I have no idea on how to approach this problem.

Is there any solution for this problem that I'm missing ?

*NOTE:I found the [discussion](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues/15986) on github about this issue, and tried to install octave using the tap **dpo/openblas** that they suggest on the discussion thread [link](http://www.schoeps.org/home/2018/01/how-to-compile-gnu-octave-with-openblas-on-macos/), with no success.*

*I also read that installing it through **MacPorts** works like a charm, however since I've been using **Homebrew** for a long time, and I wouldn't like to have two package managers in my system, so I would like to approach this solution as the last resource*